# What is the equivalent of VIsual C++'s _waccess() on linux?

Tags: linux

There is the POSIX `access()`, but I'm looking for a wide character version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "wide-character filename" on Linux. Get the system charset via `nl_langinfo()` and encode to that charset before calling `access()`.

Comment: Don't forget to `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` first -- all C programs start in the C locale, you must switch to the environment-specified locale manually.

Comment: Thanks. In a way this is a pity, 'cos it looks like you can't mix languages when naming files. Can you?

Comment: UNIX **filenames** are just a array of bytes, language/encoding is not specified; it's up to each individual application to interpret those bytes however they wish.  (Yes, this does seem archaic.  That's because it is.)  So yes, you could use different encodings for different filenames, but someone else traversing the filesystem would not understand.  These days, though, all modern Linux distros use UTF-8 by default -- same encoding regardless of language.

Comment: Thanks. I don't run linux all that often and this is good to know ... and with a sigh of relief actually.